# Does oracle allow Select on table when whole table is locked by delete sql

Tags: database, oracle, database-locking

When oracle executes a delete sql(with no where clause), it locks the whole table. So while the data is getting deleted from a table by a particular user session and if during that time period, will oracle allow any other user sessions to read data from the same table as the table is being locked?

```
delete from tran_records;
```

Will there be any difference in behaviour for the above scenario in optimistic and pessimistic locking?

Answer (score 0):

Readers are never (b)locked, so - yes, `select` will work, that user will see all data in the table UNTIL `delete` operation is committed. Then nobody will see anything as there'll be no data in the table (not talking about flashback here).